# How to extract OLE objects from DOORS

Tags: ole, ibm-doors

Is it possible to extract OLE objects via DXL in DOORS 9.5.2?

To extract OLE objects from DOORS via DXL, does the server/client need the respective software to be installed? Example: if there are MS Word based OLE objects then do I need the Microsoft Office software to be installed on my client / server ?

Is it somehow possible to extract the contents of OLE objects without the target application being installed? Can this be done via any external program?

Answer (score 2):

There are ways via DXL to manipulate OLEs, however if you need to extract information from the OLE you do need the originating application or one that can read files of that type to be present on the client. For instance, you may not need Microsoft Word to read a word document but you need a program installed on the client that can.

Comment: thanks. Task here is to take OLE objects from DOORS and attach them as OLE in another DOORS system. The sever where the application is running does not have the products like Excel, Word etc. Of course when a user opens these OLE in their system they should/must have the required application

Comment: That may be tricky, the DXL script runs on one DOORS server. I am not sure you would be able to log in to two DOORS systems and transfer the OLE from one to the other. Is there a reason you wouldn't use an Archive and Restore to move the entire document or project?

Comment: Transferring one set of modules to another DOORS system. This isn't a complete backup and restore. We use inhouse application along with DXL. OLE without the respective software is proving to be tricky. I was wondering if OLE can be transferred like an attachment from one system to another

Comment: It looks like you should be able to do this using oleCopy. You might need to come up with some external script that is triggering dxl in one system to copy the OLE, then trigger the script in the other system to trigger an olePaste. Since this function uses the System Clipboard it should work, regardless of the system having the application installed.

Comment: Another approach to access different DOORS servers is to create an application that instantiate two DOORS COM objects where each is connecting to a different database.
Hint: Use the clipboard for transferring the OLE objects.A good place to start is this script: [link](http://www.galactic-solutions.com/downloads/GalacticDownloadExcel.htm)